# Android Studio - Auto Import to the import list on the top of the file but not the current line of code

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Recently when I use the auto import in android studio, it adds the import to the current line of code, instead of adding the import to the top of the class/file. How to fix it?

For example, when importing `java.util.Arrays`, it does:

```
class A {
  void foo() {
    java.util.Arrays.asList(val1, val2);
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class A {
  void foo() {
    Arrays.asList(val1, val2);
  }
}
```

This happened in a sudden. I did not change any settings. Previously it worked fine but recently it is not able to do auto import to the import list.

Comment: What imports are already in the file? Specifically, is there already an `Arrays` from some other package?

Comment: @Abby There's no other import under the name of `Arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure you have no tick in the `(File | Settings) / (IntelliJIDEA | Preferences)` `Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports` tab, **Use fully qualified class names** checkbox.

Comment: Thank, but I didn't check that box. The problem still exists.

Comment: Do you have `Enable EditorConfig support` option enabled under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`? What Android Studio version you're using?

Comment: Please export IDE settings using `File | Manage IDE Settings | Export Settings...` and upload the archive at https://uploads.jetbrains.com for the investigation. (don't forget to specify the UploadID here)